# how do i get the min from a linq to dataset query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-3.5

Hi i have a linq query below

> var Free = (from row in
>   dt.AsEnumerable()
>                           where row.Field("AppointmentType")
>   == "FreeTime"
>                           select new{ row.Field("BookedDate")
>                                        row.Field("TravelTime")}).Min()

what i want to do is have a minimum on the travelTime field and im not sure on how to do it i have looked on google and also on the msdn site but i cant seem to make head or tail of it

does anyone have any ideas??

Many thanks

Comment: I replaced the tag C#3.5 as there is no such thing. The current version numbers are CLR 2.0, C# 3.0, .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an overload for `Enumerable.Min()`:

```
var Free = (
  from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
  where row.Field("AppointmentType") == "FreeTime"
  select new {
    BookedDate = row.Field("BookedDate"),
    TravelTime = row.Field("TravelTime")
  }
).Min(x => x.TravelTime);
```

Actually, there is no need to look at the `BookedDate` and you should instead use

```
var Free = (
  from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
  where row.Field("AppointmentType") == "FreeTime"
  select row.Field("TravelTime")
).Min();
```

I kept your original code with a few modifications to demonstrate the syntax for creating anonymous types.

Comment: thank you for your help on this have inserted your suggestion and it works